# How do you get back the value of the button press instead of destroying the window?

Tags: python, tkinter

How can I change my code so that I can use the value of the pressed button, instead of destroying the window?

```
from tkinter import *

window=Tk()
window.geometry('905x560')

letters=["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"]


for i in range(len(letters)):

    ButtonLetter=Button(window, text=letters[i], command=window.destroy)
    ButtonLetter.place(x=905/9*(i-((i//9)*9))+35, y=225+100*(i//9))

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: You seem to already know how to call a command when you click a button, so what problem are you having in calling a different command? It's not clear what you really need help with, unless you're simply asking us to write the program for you/

Comment: BTW: you could use `enumerate()` instead of `range(len())`, and `string.ascii_lowercase` instead od `["a", "b", ...]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change `command=window.destroy` in your button to your requested function you want to call.

change the button definition to the following so you will call to your function with the button name you pressed as a parameter:

```
ButtonLetter=Button(window, text=letters[i], command=lambda name=letters[i]:pressed(name))
```

For example run this code:

```
from Tkinter import *

window=Tk()
window.geometry('905x560')

letters=["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"]

def pressed(label):
    print label

for i in range(len(letters)):
    ButtonLetter=Button(window, text=letters[i], command = lambda name=letters[i]:pressed(name))
    ButtonLetter.place(x=905/9*(i-((i//9)*9))+35, y=225+100*(i//9))

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! Works perfectly!